# Android Firebase Cloud Messaging Token (FCM) token is too short/incomplete

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging

I've been working with Azure Notification Hub the past few days, trying to set up push notifications in ASP NET and Dart/Kotlin. I've been struggling with FCM/PNS tokens.

When I register my app, I get this token: `ddGYUP9OSdi2YR9Y******` using * just in case.

At one point in development, I found I had a registration associated with Hubs with the token: `ddGYUP9OSdi2YR9Y******:APA91bMANCn_SZQV8bUJCWOiyPzdXaBPrqLmqIk8ELj6RfCx5TKNR2hLmiNMfuyK7LdY70-BtMxxyRbituhPH2t5v9p0A-8qkCleEgOWi4cXcvKpxedW2QmqEmym-hk8oZOXdx-*****`

It's the same token, but with something added after the semi colon. What is this, and where does it come from?

I get the first token from `FirebaseInstallations.getInstance().id`, and with every device I register with the tokens are a similar length. However in my ASP NET project, sending a notification to a device only works with the longer token. When I test a notification using the Firebase Console: Firebase - Engage - Cloud Messaging - Compose Notification, only the long one works. Which leads me to believe there's a problem in my registration code.

So what is that extra stuff after the colon on the short token?

My code for getting the FCM token for those interested.

```
private fun getDeviceToken() : String {
  if(!playServicesAvailable) {
    throw Exception(getPlayServicesError())
  }

  val token = PushNotificationsFirebaseMessagingService.token

  if (token.isNullOrBlank()) {
    throw Exception("Unable to resolve token for FCM.")
  }

  return token
}
```

Comment: The short one that you get from FirebaseInstallations.getInstance().id is the `deviceId` while the long one is a combo of `deviceId:token` and that is the one used to direct a push-message to the actual device-app-install-combo.

Answer (score 0):

The assumption, that the token string would end at the colon, is just wrong ...
That `PushNotificationsFirebaseMessagingService` simply returns an invalid token
and the question doesn't have any `PushNotificationsFirebaseMessagingService`.

```
if (token.isNullOrBlank() || !token.contains(":")) {
    throw IllegalArgumentException("bad or no token given")
}
```

Comment: I never assumed it was, the question was asking for more information on what the FCM token is. All my code is the same as tutorial code provided by firebase/microsoft, if you want it i can prove it.

Comment: It is extremely unclear, what `PushNotificationsFirebaseMessagingService` even is. You cannot ask questions about it, unless providing it. The `registration_id` (token) should have 152-326 chars (give or take).

Answer (score 0):

Found the problem. A microsoft doc had

```
FirebaseInstallations
                    .getInstance()
                    .id
                    .addOnCompleteListener(OnCompleteListener { task ->
                        if (!task.isSuccessful) {
                            return@OnCompleteListener
                        }

                        PushNotificationsFirebaseMessagingService.token = task.result
                        PushNotificationsFirebaseMessagingService.notificationRegistrationService?.refreshRegistration()
                    })
```

In on create. So that 'token' was just the installation Id.

The correct code for the token, as shown in Firebase docs is

```
FirebaseMessaging.getInstance().token.addOnCompleteListener(OnCompleteListener { task ->
                if(!task.isSuccessful) {
                    print("Fetching FCM registration token failed")
                    return@OnCompleteListener
                }

                val token = task.result
                PushNotificationsFirebaseMessagingService.token = token;
            })
```